# Apache Camel and Ruby

Tags: ruby, message-queue, apache-camel, enterprise-integration

I'm developing a solution that uses Ruby, Stomp and ActiveMQ. As I wish to implement some message routing patterns (as in Enterprise Integration Patterns), I'm wondering if there is a gem to interface Ruby and Apache Camel, or other message routing/integration framework that can be used with Ruby/Stomp (or Beanstalk)/ActiveMQ.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

STOMP is language neutral protocol, so you if you have a ruby stomp client and a java stomp client (eg the activemq-camel JAR) then you can integrate Camel with Ruby.

There is also a camel-ruby component which allows you to define Camel routes in Ruby language. However the EIP/DSL in Camel may have changed since, and the camel-ruby component may not be up to date. There is some examples in the test source folder of the camel-ruby component.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can choose to run on top of TorqueBox, JRuby based Ruby implementation running on top of JBoss application server, which provides you a full JMS bridge. Then you can use standard EIP projects from Java world like Apache ServiceMix/Camel or JBoss Drools/jBPM.